# Entity framework user defined property is ignored

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have a class with a property that contains getter and setter. 
The idea was simple - Store at the DB a collection and map it into dictionary in the property setter. 
**However, this property is ignored**. 
When I switch to the same property with automatic getter and setter everything works.
This is not lazy-eager loading issue since the other documented property loads as expected.

```
public class RatesBoard 
{ 
    #region Ctor 

    public RatesBoard() 
    { 
        ID = -1; 
        Rates = new List<Rate>(); 
    } 

    #endregion 

    #region Members And Properties 

    private Dictionary<string, Rate> _rates = new Dictionary<string, Rate>(); 

    /// <summary> 
    /// The rates board ID 
    /// </summary> 
    [Key] 
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public int ID { get; set; } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// The rates as flat list 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <remarks>Notice that this is a cloned list so any additions to add will not reflect in the board</remarks> 
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> Rates 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _rates.Values.ToList(); 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            _rates.Clear(); 

            if (value != null) 
            { 
                foreach (Rate rate in value) 
                { 
                    _rates.Add(rate.RelatedCountryID, rate); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    //This one works!!!!
    //public virtual ICollection<Rate> Rates 
    //{ 
    //    get; 
    //    set; 
    //} 
    #endregion 

    #region Methods 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Returns the rate for a country 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="countryUNId">The country UN id</param> 
    /// <returns>The country rate or null if there is no entry for that country</returns> 
    public Rate GetRateDetails(string countryUNId) 
    { 
        if (!_rates.ContainsKey(countryUNId)) 
        { 
            return null; 
        } 

        return _rates[countryUNId]; 
    } 

    #endregion 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand EF correctly, during object materialization it will add items to a list if the list is not `null`. Otherwise it will use the underlying member variable to initialize the list. (I think so, because EF can also materialize collection properties without setters).

The line

```
return _rates.Values.ToList();
```

Always returns a new list. That means that EF will use this list to add items to. It will not use the member variable `_rates`, nor will it use the setter. So the items are added to a transient list. The next time you access it, you see a **new transient list without items**. Maybe this explanation is not entirely spot-on, but I'm sure it's close enough.

The auto property is the preferred style. Not only because it makes EF work, but also because it's commonly discouraged to put much logic in property setters or getters. The word "property" conveys that it's simply a value you can get or set. Maybe you can put some validation in there, some lazy initialization for convenience, but not anything that does more than the expected behavior: "I set this value, now my object *has* this value".

Comment: Great answer but I don't count the implementation as much logics inside a property. I want to avoid duplications of classes so I'm doing some compromise and a bit more than POCO\DTO...